# Not able to fetch percentage in fixed column bars in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, percentage

Hi i am new to highcharts and facing a difficulty in getting a proper fixed column chart which deals with percentage values.

I would like:

[image: chart with stacked bars]

But i am able to achieve:

[image: chart with plain bars]

Comment: Could you reproduce it in online code editor like jsfiddle?

Comment: Hey, you can find my code here. https://jsfiddle.net/64cvyeof/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format data labels using `series.dataLabels.formatter` callback. Check demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```
  series: [{
    name: 'NSV',
    color: 'rgba(165,170,217,1)',
    data: [38891, 35098, 21296, 19345, 19092],
    pointPadding: 0.3,
    pointPlacement: -0.2
  }, {
    name: 'Margin',
    color: 'rgba(126,86,134,.9)',
    data: [8594.911, 6422.934, 5302.704, 580.35, 3417.468],
    pointPadding: 0.4,
    pointPlacement: -0.2,
    dataLabels: {
     formatter: function() {
      var chart = this.series.chart,
        percentage = (this.y / chart.series[0].points[this.point.index].y) * 100;

        return percentage.toFixed(1) + '%';
     }
    }
  }]
```

**Demo:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pxLmjvkh/1/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.dataLabels.formatter

Comment: You're welcome;) If this answer was helpful, please upvote or mark it as a correct one, thanks.